# How to pass data from android project (main activity ) to libgdx core project class

Tags: android, libgdx

I created interface to perform inapp billing in android, after successful purchase , i want to pass string so that i can use in game play.
Like user purchased extra life, then i should increase the count, how to achieve this.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Comment: i am using same, but how do i pass result to core java class

Comment: with interfaces maybe?

Comment: @Paul can you provide any sample code

Comment: Well you created the core java class inside your android activity class, so you can just call a method on it from there if you need. If you want to go for a more generic approach, you could use a listener interface, but that's probably over complicating in your case.

Comment: Xoppa posted the link to the code you need!

Answer (score 3):

In your android part save a refrence to your game:

```
Game game = new Game(this)       
View gameView = initializeForView(game, cfg);
layout.addView(gameView)
```

Now you are able to call any method in your libgdx game using:

```
        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                game.callMethod();
            }
        })
```